# Uncaught TypeError: items.filter is not a function when using autocomplete in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I tried to do the auto complete in my form. But some error occurs like,
`Uncaught TypeError: items.filter is not a function`

```
 {patientsMasterData.ReferredBy && patientsMasterData.ReferredBy.map((referredObj) =>
                    <div className="add-list_value">

                    <ReactAutocomplete
                                name="ReferredBy"
                                items = {
                                  ({options:referredObj.RefName, 
                                   values:referredObj.RefID})
                                }
                                shouldItemRender={(item, value) => (item.options.toLowerCase().indexOf(value)) > -1}
                                getItemValue={(item) => item.options}
                                renderItem={(item, highlighted) =>
                                    <div
                                    key={item.values}
                                    style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? '#afafaf' : '#efefef'}}
                                    >
                                    {item.options}
                                    </div>
                                }
                                menuStyle={this.props.menuStyle}
                                wrapperStyle={this.props.wrapperStyle}
                                value={this.state.value}
                                onChange={e => this.setState({ value:e.target.value })}
                                onSelect={value => this.setState({ value })}

                       />

                    </div>
                     )}
```

This is my code.. Can anybody help me sort out this problem?

Comment: Its a simple typo, `items = {
                                  [{options:referredObj.RefName, 
                                   values:referredObj.RefID}]
                                }` instead of  `[]` you have used `()` brackets

Comment: Ok the error gone, but dropdown values doesn't shown

Comment: Can you console.log `{options:referredObj.RefName, 
                                   values:referredObj.RefID}` and see if the object contains the correct values and also log in `renderItem` function to see that the `item.options` has correct value to return

Comment: Ya, I already got the value yesterday. But for some alignment I changed something.. But I don't remember what I did... It's a small change I know, but what? Could you please please help me??

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: I can't point out what is wrong with your code.Probably is you create a sandbox or a reproducible demo, I can debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183937/discussion-between-jane-fred-and-shubham-khatri).